# Power supply issues for half-bridge IGBT driver

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, gate-driving, igbt

We are designing an isolated power supply for our IGBT Driver. We took the reference design from [this](https://www.loneoceans.com/labs/sales/brickdriver/) & [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduea3/tiduea3.pdf?ts=1662398739051)

This is reference design 1:

[image]

This is reference design 2:

[image]

We are using a zener diode (MMSZ4702T1G) and a resistor (10 kΩ) to split +24 V into +15 V and -8 V, but when we connect the load +15V decreases to +12V and -8V decreases to -12V.

Here is our schematic:

[image]

How can we improve this design, and how much current can be drawn from this setup?

Are there any alternatives for generating an isolated +15 V and -8 V from a single supply?

Comment: What voltage does the IGBT switch? What dv/dt? What isolation capacitance is needed?

Answer (score 1):

What is the resistance of the load? The 10k resistor supplies less than 1 mA to the zener, so your load on the 15V supply can't draw much more than half that current. If that is a half watt 15V zener, you should have at least 10 mA, which would be about 800 ohms.

Another approach might be a negative VR like 7915 for the high side supply, or a 7808 for low side supply.

It would help to see details of the components connected to the gate driver output.

Comment: +15V and -8V is connected to IGBT Driver (HCPL-316J)

Comment: If you read the datasheet https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Avago%20PDFs/HCPL-316J.pdf, you will see that the output supply current Icc2 is 5-10 mA. So I would use about 500 ohms for R70.

Comment: Icc2 flows from Vcc2 to Vee though, not Ve.  Ve is rated for about -0.4mA -- which is relatively large compared to the 0.8mA in the schematic, but shouldn't be the actual problem if this is the case. That said, they only give Ieh/Iel at Ve = Vee, and do not seem to mention what it is for intermediate voltages(!).